# Make a relative layout take all space vertically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I created the following linear layout. Depending on the amount of data I want to display in a single row, I remove views.

For example, if I only have 1 element, I place it in `v0` and make `part1`'s visibility to `View.GONE`.

If I have 3 elements, I can place one in `v0`, make `v1`'s visibility `View.GONE`, and insert the others into `v2` and `v3`.

[image]

In that specific case, if the item in `v0` is large and the ones in `v2` and `v3` are small, I would like these to fill in their area. However, I'm unable to do so. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

This is the wrapper linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        tools:background="#484"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/v0"
            tools:minHeight="50dp"
            tools:background="#59dfdb"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            tools:minHeight="50dp"
            tools:background="#0a3ac9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/part1"
        tools:background="#484"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            tools:minHeight="50dp"
            tools:background="#cd59df"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/v3"
            tools:minHeight="50dp"
            tools:background="#86c90a"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout of the items that would go into `v2` and `v3` is a relative layout. The outermost layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing">

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        tools:background="#00ffe1"
        tools:text="Title goes here, which may or may not be super duper extra long"
        android:textSize="@dimen/node_default_text_title_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/node_default_spacing_quarter"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/node_default_spacing_half"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/node_default_spacing_half"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/node_default_spacing_quarter"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I've make it `android:layout_height="match_parent"` but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any tips on how to get this to stretch vertically?

Thanks!

Comment: I am kinda confused? So I think it should be taking all the space but your android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing" padding the content.

Comment: That's smallish.. `10dp`. So I don't believe it's that.

Comment: Try LinearLayout as outermost layout of v2 and v2 and place RelativeLayout inside.

Comment: @Yuliwee The outermost layout of `v2` and `v3` is already a `LinearLayout`. It's the one with `id` of `part1`. And the layout I place inside `v2` and `v3` is already a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Yeah well, I'm pretty confused as well, as you write "The outermost layout is ... <RelativeLayout..."

Comment: @Yuliwee v0, v1, v2 ,v3 are all empty LinearLayouts. The view I insert programmatically in each of these is a RelativeLayout. Does that make sense? I've included the first part of the RelativeLayout

Comment: So where can I see this RelativeLayout in your screenshot? The background color should be #cb3ce7 which is kind of violet. But I cannot see it anywhere? You should also provide your code if you do much stuff programatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162190/discussion-between-zundi-and-yuliwee).